# Manipulate Keystroke via Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to manipulate the keystrokes before it is entered to the Chrome browser （web page) by javascript or chrome extensions (for example, change all characters to uppercase)? I want to do something similar to the example provided by Google (change all characters entered to uppercase) but Chrome input.ime API only works for Chrome OS.

My main purpose is to change inputs to Google docs, the text field of google doc is not a input or textarea, so I think the only way to do this is to change the keystroke from the beginning, any idea how to change input to google doc is great!

The Chrome input.ime API example is here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/input.ime/basic/

Comment: add a little more detail to help with an answer

Comment: Actually, the ime api should work on Linux and Windows. https://crbug.com/607425

Comment: In what situations are you wanting to change the key information? For example: for input into a web page? input into Chrome's URL bar? Where?

Comment: As with anything like there where you want to interpose your own processing: use a content script that is run at `document_start` which adds a listener (capture phase, not bubbling) for the event on the `window`, which executes `.preventDefault()` and `.stopImmediatePropagation()`. Then, create a new event which does what you want and dispatch it. You may have issues with `isTrusted`.

Comment: @Makyen It seems that there is an error on the dispatchEvent() function, is it because of isTrusted? Please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729709/how-to-dispatch-keyboardevent-in-chrome-extensions) and see whether is the code or something within the Chrome? Thank you!