# How to dispatch KeyboardEvent in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

Does Chrome allow firing KeyboardEvent by using content script in Extensions? I was trying to change every character entered to the page to the same character, but when I load the extension, the "dispatchEvent()" function gave me "Uncaught RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded", can someone check my code? Thanks!

So in the content script I first standard keyboard input, then create a new keyboardevent and dispatch it. The error is on "dispatchEvent()" function.

Manifest.JSON

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Input_Enc",
    "description": "This is to encrypt the input",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action":{
        "default_title": "Test"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
    {   "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "myScript.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
    ]

}
```

myScript.js

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", myFunc);

function myFunc(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    evt.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 69, 69);
    evt.keyCode = 69;
    evt.which = 69;
    evt.charCode = 69;
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime or https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger and https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Input/#method-dispatchKeyEvent

Comment: @DanielHerr  looks like input.ime only works for other OS in Chromium? I cannot directly apply input.ime under Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't seem to either, you can comment on https://crbug.com/607425

Comment: Every time a key is pressed, you stop the event, and fire a new one. You then stop that event and fire a new one, which you stop and fire a new one... forever. Or at least until: you get to: `Uncaught RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded`